# How to control template rendering based on if returned errors? Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to show a loading GIF after the user submits the form but not if the user failed to fill a required field and received a form filling error.

This is what I did:

```
 {% if not profile_form.errors %}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " onclick="loading();" />
{% else %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />

{% endif %}
```

The `onclick="loading();` loads the GIF.

But it doesn't work.

It shows the loading gif if I submit also if the user didn't fill a required field, which gives a look that the form is hanged.

This is the function:

```
function loading(){
    $("#loading").show();
    $("#content").hide();       
}
```

This is the template:

```
{% block body_block %}
<div id="loading"><img src= "{% static 'images/giphy.gif' %}"></div>

<div id="content" class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" style="margin-top: 100px;margin-bottom: 100px" >

<h1>Create Your Profile</h1>

    <form method="post" action="?next=/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}                     
                 {{ user_form|crispy }}
                 {{ profile_form|crispy }}

 {% if not profile_form.errors %}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " onclick="loading();" />
{% else %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />

{% endif %}
        </form>     

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the CSS:

```
/*LOADING GIF*/
div#loading {
    display: none;
    cursor: wait;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 4;
    }
```

Comment: *But it doesn't work.* Expand on that. At least the GIF gets shown until the form gets validated in the view since the first rendering from the view will have no errors. You could instead use a JS validation.

Comment: post the function code? and where have you declared your function?

Comment: I added an edit.

Comment: So after the submit. You are seeing the loading the gif about few seconds and then disappear ? Or You don't see the loading gif at all. ?

Comment: I see you are submitting the form via HTML POST form submit. When you do that it will load the send the post to server and reload the page to display the return message. If you want to load the gif and hide after success. You need to do it as javascript form submit

Comment: It shows the loading gif if I submit also if the user didn't fill a required field, which gives a look that the form is hanged. I want to show the gif only if the form didn't show any filling errors like mistyping an email address or not filling a required field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood the logic flow here. There are no errors until *after* the form is submitted, and the view has re-rendered the template to show those errors. At the point the form is first submitted, there will never be any errors at all so your if statement is always true.

As Raja says in the comments, the only way to do this is to submit the form via Ajax, and then also show the gif via JS.

Comment: About time you're here! Saved tons of our time! :)